# Why is the index applied to the inequality sign different depending on the direction? (mysql index)

Tags: mysql, indexing

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

When the table is created like this, whether the using index is used depends on whether the direction of the inequality sign is a number or a field, so I'm curious as to why.

1. Using Index

```
explain select * from test_table kcs where kcs.id < 10 ORDER by id DESC;
```

2. Using where; Using filesort

```
explain select * from test_table kcs where kcs.id > 10 ORDER by id DESC;
```

Comment: *Why is the index applied to the inequality sign different depending on the direction? (mysql index)* The amount of rows matched the condition differs, for example - this may result in different execution plans. PS. MySQL 8 shows me *Using where; Backward index scan; Using index*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1 (not many rows in the range): use the index.

Case 2 (lots of rows in the range): Scan the table instead of bouncing between the index and the data.

In reality, since you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, then both of them *may* be performed in a similar manner.

Your test table is too watered down -- Nothing but one column, the PK.  If you are experimenting with MySQL, give it a bit more meat, *else you may be led into false or confusing conclusions*.